# How can I add the platform toolset of Visual Studio 2005 into the `Platform Toolset` list of the newer IDE versions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2005-2015. I am to use the platform toolset of Visual Studio 2005, but this variant is absent in the list:

[image]

How can I add the platform toolset of Visual Studio 2005 into the `Platform Toolset` list of the newer IDE versions?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) (first Google hit for "add visual studio 2005 platform toolset")? Is it applicable to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `v100` is `MS VC 2010` toolset
- `v90` is `MS VC 2008` toolset
- `v80` is `MS VC 2005` toolset, this is what you are looking for.

Follow the procedure below and setup `MS VC 2005 Platform Toolset`.

- Create `v80` folder in `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets`
- Copy `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v100.props` & `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v100.targets` files from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v100`

to

`C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v80`

- Rename copied files to `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v80.props` & `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v80.targets`
- Edit the files, point to `VisualStudio\8.0`, change `110` to `80` or `8.0` as appropriate
- Edit the project settings, Change platform tool set to `v80`

Rebuild the project, That's all!

Comment: you are just copying v100 settings and renaming them to v80

Comment: remove also .NET > 2.0 support ( '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' != 'v3.0' and ...) If you are using WindowsSDK you will need to change project paths to point to PlatformSDK 8.0 as well. And if you are using CLI you will need to edit project file to use .NET 2.0.

Comment: Also change the boolean values within <ResourceCompile> and <ManifestResourceCompile> from true to false, to avoid the error "RC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo".

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem for all versions by installing the daffodil software from 
https://daffodil.codeplex.com/downloads/get/347180